# Android : nonwritablechannelException and ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, android

I'm using `FileLock`, but I don't know why I always meet `nonwritablechannelException exception` :

```
public static List<String> readFromFile(Context ctx, String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput(filename);
            // lock this file
            FileLock lock = fis.getChannel().tryLock(); // Exception here
            // unlock this file
            lock.release();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cannot read file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

And I meet another exception when I writting from file: Exception `ClosedChannelException`

```
public static boolean saveToFile(Context ctx, List<String> lst, String filename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // lock this file
            FileLock lock = fos.getChannel().lock();
            PackageObject obj = new PackageObject(lst);
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            writer.writeObject(obj);
            writer.close();
            // unlock this file
            lock.release(); // Exception at this line
                fos.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cannot write file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

On Android Developer page, they explain this exception is:

> A NonWritableChannelException is thrown when attempting to write to a
>   channel that is not open for writing.

But I still cannot explain why. Please help me figure out why I meet this exception please.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "A NonWritableChannelException is thrown when attempting to write to a channel that is not open for writing."

You opened the file/channel using `openFileInput` ... which is opening it for reading not writing.  If you want to take a lock on the file, you have to open it for write using `openFileOutput` instead ... or maybe as well.

Comment: I have two problems : 1) I want to lock for reading too, how can I do this. 2) The code for writting (use as you say above), I meet exception : `ClosedChannelException` at line `lock.release` can you explain why ? I have edited my post, please see again. Thanks :)

Comment: 1) Have you tried using `openFileInput` AND `openFileOutput` together?  That's what I suggested in my answer.  2)  It seems to be saying that you should release the lock BEFORE you close the file.

Comment: 1) `AND` I don't really understand it, please tell me more clearer. 2) as the code I edited, I release the lock before i close the file. And I still meet this err. Thanks :)